# customizing java code generation of wsimport

Tags: java, wsimport

In my XSD I've the following type definition:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Color">
    <xs:annotation />
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="B">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <codeName>BLUE</codeName>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="R">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <codeName>RED</codeName>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Out of the box wsimport would generate the following java enum out of it:

```
public enum Color {
    B,
    R;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static Color fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

I'd like wsimport to consider the long descriptions in the codename elements `<codeName>BLUE</codeName>` and include them as an instance variable in the java enum. Is this prossible for example by using an JAXB binding file?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a one-to-one mapping of values by providing a [JAXB bindings file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).  Within the bindings file, you would want something like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               jaxb:version="2.0">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:simpleType[@name='Color']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="R" name="RED" />
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="B" name="BLUE" />
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings>
```

Alternatively, you could provide the JAXB bindings inline within the schema, but I do not like that approach because it clutters the schema with implementation details that will probably not apply to everyone.

An example of that is below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           jxb:version="1.0">

    <xs:simpleType name="Color">
        <!--xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation-->
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="B">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BLUE" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="R">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="RED" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

You could also do it all at once, with it being a bit disjoint from the actual values, therefore a bit more duplicative:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           jxb:version="1.0">

    <xs:simpleType name="Color">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="RED" />
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BLUE" />
                </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="B" />
            <xs:enumeration value="R" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your approch has 2 disadvantages:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your approach has 2 disadvantages: 1. I have to maintain all enum values in the JAXB binding file. I'd prefer a solution which could automatically map all <codeName> elements. 2. Suppose I had `<codeName>A long description</codename>`. This is not a valid Java identifier and therefore I could not use it as typesafeEnumMember name.

Comment: @samson If it could map them automatically, then it would certainly be the way, but there is no way to know what is intended in all cases that I am aware of. You can provide JAXB bindings directly within the file, which provides the self-documenting with the implementation (JAXB), but it is clutter to me (mostly personal taste). If you want a `codeName` that is invalid, then you can supply that as a separate element (I would recommend as `xs:documentation`) in this way.

Comment: I still don't like this solution. Regardless weather using typesafemember entry inline or in an external file the disadvantage remains, that I've to maintain all the mappings. Whenever the XSD changes and a new enumeration value is added, I've to add a new enumeration entry.